# Sharing Address to two entities - Polymorphic association or two addresses tables?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, polymorphic-associations, model-associations

I'm pretty new at Ruby on Rails and i'm not sure what is the best approach to modelling the application.

My app has an User model and a Restaurant model. Both of them has only one address.

Restaurants table

```
create_table "restaurants", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.text     "description"
 t.string   "email"
 t.string   "phone"
 t.integer  "category_id"
 t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
end
```

User table

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "first_name"
 t.string   "surname"
 t.string   "email"
 t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
end
```

The restaurants addresses must have two columns more than the users addresses ( lat and long)

FIRST APPROACH - Create two tables, one to the restaurant addresses and another to the user addressses.

User addresses table

```
create_table "user_addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "street"
 t.string   "city"
 t.string   "zip_code"
 t.integer  "user_id"
 t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
 t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_addresses_on_user_id"
end
```

restaurant addresses table

```
create_table "restaurant_addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "street"
 t.string   "city"
 t.string   "zip_code"
 t.decimal  "longitude"
 t.decimal  "latitude"
 t.integer  "restaurant_id"
 t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
 t.index ["restaurant_id"], name: "index_addresses_on_restaurant_id"
end
```

SECOND APPROACH -

1. Create a Polymorphic association for the User model and Restaurant model.
2. Create a separated table with the coordinates (associated just with the restaurant Model).

Polymorphic Association

```
class User
 has_one :address, as: :addressable
end

class Restaurant
 has_one :address, as: :addressable
 has_one:coordinate
end

class Address
 belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Any one of this approachs are good enough or is it a better way to do that?

Comment: What's the business logic that's going to operate on these objects?

Comment: Sorry for the delay John,

Update: The User table also need to has the columns for coordinates. I will use that to calculate the distance between User addresses and Restaurants addresses. In this case what do you recommend?